# Webpack can not load font file: Unexpected Token

Tags: css, fonts, webpack

I have a *style.css* file that makes use of a font file, and I'm having trouble getting the font file loaded using Webpack. Here is my loader configuration:

```
    loaders    : [
        {
            test    : /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude : /node_modules/,
            loader  : 'react-hot!babel-loader'
        }, {
            test   : /\.styl/,
            loader : 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
        }, {
            test   : /\.css$/,
            loader : 'style-loader!css-loader'
        }, {
            test   : /\.(png|jpg)$/,
            loader : 'url-loader?limit=8192'
        }, {
            test   : /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2))(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
            loader : 'file-loader'
        }
        /*}, {
         test : /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
         loader : 'url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff'*/
    ]
```

The errors that I receive is

```
ERROR in ./src/fonts/icon/fonts/mf-font.woff?lt4gtt
Module parse failed: /PATH/src/fonts/icon/fonts/mf-font.woff?lt4gtt Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./~/css-loader!./src/fonts/icon/style.css 2:293-331
```

It looks to me that Webpack is taking it as a CSS file when it's not. But I'm pretty sure the test expression passes for the font file

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The regex in your test expression has a small mistake. `woff(2)` means that it always looks for `woff2` and just captures the `2` in a separate group. If you add a `?` after it, webpack should be able to recognize `woff` as well:

```
test   : /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9=&.]+)?$/,
loader : 'file-loader'
```

Please let me know if this worked.

Comment: Couldn't believe it was over such a silly mistake, thanks

Comment: Why does webpack want to capture the 2 in a separate group?

Comment: It doesn't. You could also write `/\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff2?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/` or use a non-capturing group `/\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(?:2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/`. I just left the group for clarity's sake (because `woff2?` might be misread as matching either all or nothing).

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick for me:

```
{ test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
{ test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" },
```